# Auto Refresh Page (React With Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

[client folder where the react code sits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqO9g.png)I am Using react with ruby on rails, I have created a separate folder named client for react code on the root. but whenever I changed something in the react i have to go to the page and refresh it manually, is there any way where I can automatically refresh the page whenever I can make any change in the code?

Comment: just follow this one https://blog.grillwork.io/create-a-ruby-on-rails-5-1-application-with-webpack-react-16-and-react-router-e2c16d267f73

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app then it should be available through that package. If you are building your own environment with Webpack, you can use Hot Module Replacement. https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

**Edit:**

Here are some example files from a project I made containing relevant code.

*Webpack*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    resolve(__dirname, "src") + "/index.jsx"
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },

  devtool: '#source-map',

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          emitWarning: true,
          configFile: "./.eslintrc.json"
          }
        },
        {
      test: /\.(png|gif|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8000,
          name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
            "react"
          ],
          plugins: [
            "react-hot-loader/babel",
            "styled-jsx/babel"
          ]
        }
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template:'template.ejs',
      appMountId: 'react-app-root',
      title: 'Project Name',
      filename: resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"),
    }),
  ]
};
```

Mainly, the **entry**, **devServer**, **module.plugins** and **plugins** at the bottom have the hot reloading code.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "lint": "eslint src/index.jsx src/**/*.jsx; exit 0",
    "lint-fix": "eslint src/index.jsx src/**/*.jsx --fix; exit 0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "url"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "url"
  },
  "homepage": "relevant-url",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-jsx": "^2.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "webpack": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

The hot reloading packages in the **devDependencies**

*index.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <HashRouter>
        <Component/>
      </HashRouter>  
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('react-app-root')
  );
};

render(App);

/*eslint-disable */
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
    render(App);
  });
}
/*eslint-enable */
```

Notice the **AppContainer** component imported from react-hot-loader that wraps your app in **ReactDOM.render.** Also, sometimes **eslint** can interfere with hot reloading which is why it is disabled and then enabled again at the bottom of the file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: unable to do it. do you have another solution, I have just uploaded an image in the question, you can check it.
Tried mostly every solution available on the internet.

Comment: Added some example code from a project I made a few months ago.